# CellFormatting event causing rendering shakiness on .NET 4.5 application

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

In a simple .NET WinForm I have a `datagridview` that is being color painted based on the value of cells. The code is working, but the rendered form is "shaky" (that look when a computer is constantly having to redraw and can't keep up). I am wondering if there's something I can do to eliminate this, or if there's something wrong with my code. Advice appreciated.

```
private void gvPhoneQueue_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (gvPhoneQueue.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].HeaderText == "CallsWaiting")
                {
                    string convertedVal = e.Value.ToString();
                    if (Convert.ToInt32(convertedVal) > _greenTolerance)
                    {
                        gvPhoneQueue.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green;
                    }

                    if (Convert.ToInt32(convertedVal) > _yellowTolerance)
                    {
                        gvPhoneQueue.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                    }

                    if (Convert.ToInt32(convertedVal) > _redTolerance)
                    {
                        gvPhoneQueue.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                LogEvent("Error" _+ ex);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have already seen some threads about performance issue of `DataGridView` in such case (using `CellFormatting`, `CellPainting`, ...). This **could** be a "known issue" **when working with a lot a data**.

What is sure, you should avoid to do something too much complicated in `CellFormating` event. I don't see something wrong in your code, but **it doesn't seem to be optimized**:

- You use 3 times `Convert.ToInt32(convertedVal)` : you should store the value instead of convert 3 times the string value. And if you are using a `Try Cath` block, due to possible converting error, you could use instead the [`int32.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx) method.
- I guess the color can't be both red, yellow, or green, and **_redTolerence is the highest value?** So you should start by testing the highest value and then others, and so exit from the method as soon as you can and so do not evaluate the 3 `if` statements each time if not needed. In VB.Net I would recommend to use `ElseIf` statement <strike>but it does not exist in C#</strike>.Using `return` would be the same in this case.  [**EDIT**
  My mistake `else if` in C# equals `ElseIf` in VB.Net].

---

*Possible* optimization:

```
private void gvPhoneQueue_CellFormatting(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (gvPhoneQueue.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).HeaderText == "CallsWaiting") {
        int convertVal = 0;
        if (int.TryParse(e.Value.ToString, convertVal)) {
            if (convertVal > _redTolerance) {
                gvPhoneQueue.Rows(e.RowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
            } else if (convertVal > _yellowTolerance) {
                gvPhoneQueue.Rows(e.RowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
            } else if (convertVal > _greenTolerance) {
                gvPhoneQueue.Rows(e.RowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green;
            }
        } else {
            //can't convert e.value
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the optimization thing did the trick. The red, then yellow, then green was the trick. Surprisingly, though I thought you were write and the conversion was probably doing the slow down, the single conversion didn't speed it up. Also - you can just do "else if" in C#.

Comment: @Darkenor Glad that it helps. Concerning the the single conversion, maybe I'm wrong but I think the performance gain obtained by the first optimization is here but is insignificant compared to the performance gain obtained by the other optimization, because I think the part of code the more consomatrice of resources was probably the of the evaluation systematic of the 3 `if` statements. Thanks for the precision about Else If. You are right, it seems I have misread a thread. `else if` in C# equals `ElseIf` in VB. I will edit my answer.